# Always show captcha in my facebook dialog in my iOS APP

Tags: ios, facebook, captcha

I am integrating the Facebook Api in my apps.
Always works fine since some days ago that always ask my users type a captcha before post.

Has anybody any idea why it happens now?

[image]

For open the dialog, I use:

```
[delegate.facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
                andParams:params
              andDelegate:delegate];
```

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly related to the specific link you're sharing, it's most likely because the domain you're sharing the links on is being reported as spam or is a redirector or URL shortening service

There's no way to prevent it, but if you're sharing links to a well-known redirector, maybe try hosting the content on your own domain instead

Comment: wtf, detects the appstore url as spam! I can't believe it! Thanks

Comment: The app store URL itself probably shouldn't be detected as spam (at least, in my experience i've not seen much abuse by spammy apps posting their app store URLS), maybe some of the parameters are triggering a spam warning, or it's the combination of your app and the URL that are suspicious, this is likely if you're testing an app and repeatedly making and deleting posts with the URL- this looks the same as a spam attack would, when users remove the spam from their timeline afterwards